# check existence and read /proc files with Linux C program

Tags: c, linux, kernel, openwrt

I want to know how to check existence and read files (may be with C linux kernel functions) /proc/mtd and /proc/partitions in my program developped in C (for OpenWrt), without using fopen,fread,... functions?

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Why can't you use `fopen`? Are you also prohibited from using `open` and `read`?

Comment: You could use the `access(2)` system call http://linux.die.net/man/2/access

Comment: Are you coding a kernel module, and running *inside* the kernel ? Or are you coding an application or utility ? What does "linux kernel functions" mean to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine whether a file exists you could try getting the file's stats (creation time, protections, etc.).  That would not require you to open or read the file's contents.  The error code would tell you whether you simply didn't have permission to perform the action or whether the file didn't exist.

As for reading without any of the standard open and read functions, why?!  Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: the proc files are not real files in the disk. when we open a proc file a kernel function is called in order to get information from kernel and then print it. so my question is how to get the mtd information directly from the kernel without using the mtd proc file.
the application that I'm developing is a user space application.

Comment: @AhmedZRIBI: The only alternative would be to open e.g. `/dev/mtdX` and see what `ioctl()` calls are available. Using `/proc` or `/sys` should be easier. What is wrong with you using `/proc`?

Answer (score 0):

Userspace and kernel are separated. It means you can't call a kernel function from a userspace pogram. From userspace, the only way to get information from a procfile is, well, to open it and read it.